# Control scrolling in a scrollPane component with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scrollpane

Feel like I'm asking easy questions. I'm wanting to control the scrolling of a MC in a scrollPane component without clicking and dragging the scroll button. I want to use tabs located on the main timeline and outside of the scrollPane source, so that when I click on the first tab the MC inside the scrollPane scrolls to a certain spot, etc. I'm also wanting to show the actual scrolling as it's taking place, not just jump to the desired location.

I did this really basic test code which works as far as changing the location of the MC inside the scrollPane. However it doesn't change the scroll button location so I can't manually scroll back up after moving the MC's vertical location because the scroll button is still located at the top. It also doesn't show the MC scrolling (if that's even possible), it just jumps up vertically by 100:

```
scrollPane.source = movie;

scrollPane.source = new movie;

scrollTest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.source.y -= 100;
}
```

Comment: Use **horizontalScrollPosition** and **verticalScrollPosition** properties of the **ScrollPane** instance rather than directly control the content.

Comment: So would it be something like this:  function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollPane.verticalScrollPosition -= 100;
} ((Sorry, not sure how to get the text on separate line, whenever I hit the Enter button it posts instead))

Comment: @Organis - thanks again, it works in getting the scrollPane to the correct position. Is there a way of achieving the second part of my post, where you can actually see the content of the scrollPane scrolling instead of only jumping to the location?

Comment: Any transition code will do. Like, my own **Easy.custom(scrollPane, {verticalScrollPosition:100}, 1000);** https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/0792a049e3dad1ec72ce492b685dcc66b8e81e05/classes/ru/delimiter/math/Easy.as

Comment: @Organis - Thank you for that...no idea what any of it means lol. Looks like it's above my pay grade, so to speak. But I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, learn about AS3 classes and how to use them: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix--active-5789 It's not actually that difficult.